# How to rename a destructured parameter concisely in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought that I would be able to use the follow syntax but it doesn't work as expected ('renamed' not defined):

```
const test= ({ var1, var2, renamed = var3 }) => { ...
```

I see that I can just do the following, but I wondered if there is a more concise way to do it from within the parenthesis. Many thanks.

```
const test= ({ var1, var2, var3 }) => { ...
const renamed = var3; ...
```

Comment: change to `renamed: var3`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
const test = ({ var1, var2, var3: renamed }) => { ...
```

Comment: Ah, ok I tried renamed : var3, wrong way round! I don't understand why that way around though

Answer (score 2):

Your destructuring syntax is wrong, the key comes first followed by a colon `:` and then the new variable name:

`key: newName = defaultValue`

```js
const test= ({ var1, var2, var3: renamed = 2 }) =>  console.log(renamed);

var1 = 0;
var2 = 1;
var3 = 2;
test({ var1, var2, var3 })
test({ var1, var2, var3: undefined })
```